# Problema al visualizar un json capturado desde una API en mi widget Column - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

tengo un problema que no he podido resolverlo por eso acudo a ustedes para que me den una mano.
Estoy trayendo un **json** desde una API, el proceso de traer los datos va bien (uso un **print** que me muestra que si obtuve los datos), el problema se me presenta al querer mostrar esos datos del json en mis widget **`Column(children:[Text(),...])`**
Estoy trabajando con  **null safety**(tal ves esto tenga que ver en el problema pero no estoy seguro ya que en las versiones anteriores no tenia este problema)

Este es el json que obtengo:

```
[
    {
        "idCliente": "1",
        "ci": "1234567",
        "nombre": "jUAN",
        "apPaterno": "Perez",
        "apMaterno": "Fernandez",
        "correo": "juan123@gmail.com",
        "telefono": "7654321",
        "idUserss": "juan123",
        "imagenNueva": "https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/vector-el-icono-del-avatar-del-usuario-para-el-sitio-web-o-el-m%C3%B3vil-45837377.jpg",
        "imagenAnterior": "https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/vector-el-icono-del-avatar-del-usuario-para-el-sitio-web-o-el-m%C3%B3vil-45837377.jpg",
        "nombreImagenNueva": "https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/vector-el-icono-del-avatar-del-usuario-para-el-sitio-web-o-el-m%C3%B3vil-45837377.jpg",
        "directorio": "imagenes"
    }
]
```

Este es el método que se encarga de traerme el json:

```
Future<Perfil> listar() async {
  var url = 'https://midominio.com/data';
  var urlfull = Uri.parse(url);
  var response = await http.get(urlfull);

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    var result = response.body;
    var decoded = json.decode(result);
    print(decoded);
    var retornar = Perfil.fromJson(decoded);
    return retornar;
  } else {
    throw Exception('Fallo al cargar la lista');
  }
}
```

Esta es mi clase modelo para el json:

```
class Perfil {
  String idCliente;
  String ci;
  String nombre;
  String apPaterno;
  String apMaterno;
  String correo;
  String telefono;
  String idUserss;
  String imagenNueva;
  String imagenAnterior;
  String nombreImagenNueva;
  String directorio;

  Perfil({
    required this.idCliente,
    required this.ci,
    required this.nombre,
    required this.apPaterno,
    required this.apMaterno,
    required this.correo,
    required this.telefono,
    required this.idUserss,
    required this.imagenNueva,
    required this.imagenAnterior,
    required this.nombreImagenNueva,
    required this.directorio,
  });

  factory Perfil.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Perfil(
        idCliente: json["idCliente"] ?? json["idCliente"],
        ci: json["ci"] ?? json["ci"],
        nombre: json["nombre"] ?? json["nombre"],
        apPaterno: json["apPaterno"] ?? json["apPaterno"],
        apMaterno: json["apMaterno"] ?? json["apMaterno"],
        correo: json["correo"] ?? json["correo"],
        telefono: json["telefono"] ?? json["telefono"],
        idUserss: json["idUserss"] ?? json["idUserss"],
        imagenNueva: json["imagenNueva"] ?? json["imagenNueva"],
        imagenAnterior: json["imagenAnterior"] ?? json["imagenAnterior"],
        nombreImagenNueva:
            json["nombreImagenNueva"] ?? json["nombreImagenNueva"],
        directorio: json["directorio"] ?? json["directorio"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "idCliente": idCliente,
        "ci": ci,
        "nombre": nombre,
        "apPaterno": apPaterno,
        "apMaterno": apMaterno,
        "correo": correo,
        "telefono": telefono,
        "idUserss": idUserss,
        "imagenNueva": imagenNueva,
        "imagenAnterior": imagenAnterior,
        "nombreImagenNueva": nombreImagenNueva,
        "directorio": directorio,
      };
}
```

Y esta es mi clase donde muestro los datos de la API en los widgets pero me dice que el snapshot esta sin data, o sea es como si no estuviera trayendo nada en el json pero en realidad si obtengo los datos pero no los visualiza.

```
class UserPerfil extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => _UserPerfilState();
}

class _UserPerfilState extends State<UserPerfil> {
  Future<Perfil>? listaPerfil;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    listaPerfil = listar();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Mi Perfil"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        color: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
        child: CustomPaint(
          painter: CurvaSesion(mcolor: Constants.global!),
          child: FutureBuilder<Perfil>(
              future: listaPerfil,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    return Column(
                      children: [
                        Text(snapshot.data!.nombre),
                        Text(snapshot.data!.apPaterno),
                        Text(snapshot.data!.apMaterno),
                        Text(snapshot.data!.correo),
                      ],
                    );
                  } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return Center(
                        child: Text(
                            "NO SE HA CARGADO LOS DATOS: ${snapshot.hasError}"));
                  }
                } else {
                  return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                      valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(
                          Theme.of(context).buttonColor),
                    ),
                  );
                }
                return Container();
              }),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Por favor si alguien pudiera ayudarme le agradeceria, estoy pensando seriamente volver a una versión mas antigua ya que hasta ahora no he podido solucionar esto(sospechando que tal vez el null safety sea el culpable )

Comment: No te muestra ningún error la consola de depuración?

Comment: No, no me muestra ningún error, solo me muestra el print(), donde imprimo el json para verificar si me llego o no después de eso se mantiene limpia la consola.cEs muy raro esto si puedes ayudarme te agradecería.

Comment: Puedes agregar la parte del código donde está el Column con el texto?

Comment: Es en la publicacion es el ultimo codigo, el de la clase: class UserPerfil

Comment: intentaste usando directamente el future?  future: listar(),  dentro del FutureBuilder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema al parecer esta en tu variable: `decoded`, estas recibiendo un array con objetos de elementos, por tanto debes especificar la posición al momento de realizar el mapeo con tu **fromJson**,que dando de esta forma:

```
Future<Perfil> listar() async {
  var url = 'https://midominio.com/data';
  var urlfull = Uri.parse(url);
  var response = await http.get(urlfull);

 if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    var result = response.body;
    var decoded = json.decode(result);    
    print(decoded);
    var retornar = Perfil.fromJson(decoded[0]);
    return retornar;
  } else {
    throw Exception('Fallo al cargar la lista');
  }
}
```

Esto dependerá mucho de como implementes tu clase modal, pero en tu caso seria de esta forma la obtención del json.